# Ошибка в VS9 - error C2078: too many initializers

Tags: c

В чем причина? Вот код, на который ругается компилятор.

```
char ** funcParam = { "eventId", "eventName" };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что char** - это одиночный указатель на указатель, а вы что на вход подаёте?

Надо

```
char * funcParam[] = { "eventId", "eventName" };
```

UPD: { "eventId", "eventName" }  - это массив указателей, т.е.  как бы char * value[], т.е. много адресов, а char ** - это просто один указатель, один адрес в памяти. Поэтому и сообщение такое.

Comment: Вы меня на секунду опередили :)

Comment: Зато меня минусанули за что-то...

Comment: Я извиняюсь, минус убрал. Просто на момент моего прочтения код, представленный Вами, был идентичен коду приведенному в вопросе :)

Comment: Я скопировал код из вопроса и случайно нажал сохранить.. и тут же поправился.. Но был пойман на махинациях :) Вот что называется скорость света! Ужас! :)

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего, это не единственная ошибка компилятора, у меня он выдал еще и

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [8]' to 'char **'
```

Что значит, что компилятор не может преобразовать char[8], т.е. "eventId" в указатель на char.

Перепишите код, так работает:

```
char *funcParam[] = { "eventId", "eventName" };
```